# Issue with Next.js v.13 - Typescript - Axios

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js13

I'm new to typescript and next.js 13 but I'm trying to accomplish without success the retrieving of data in my component using getServerSideProps. Seems like my code it's not printing any of the console.log I'm putting in the function.

Here's my code:

```
import styles from "./menu.module.scss";
import { GetServerSideProps, InferGetServerSidePropsType } from "next";
import AzureApi, { Page } from "../../../lib/azureApi";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useLocale } from "next-intl";
import Link from "next/link";

interface MenuProps {
  pages: Page[];
  open: boolean;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    // Initialize the Azure API instance
    const azureApi = new AzureApi();
    const locale = useLocale();

    // Declare detailed params to request pages details
    const pagesParams = {
      onlyTitle: true,
    };

    // Fetch initial data for users, pages, and posts
    const pages = await azureApi.getPages(locale, pagesParams);

    return {
      props: {
        pages,
      },
      revalidate: 1, // tempo in secondi con cui next verifica presenza update da api
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching pages:", error);
    return {
      props: {
        pages: [],
      },
    };
  }
};

export const Menu = (
  { open }: MenuProps,
  { pages }: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>
) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <div
      className={open ? [styles.active, styles.menu].join(" ") : styles.menu}
    >
      <ul className={styles.menu__content}>
        {pages.map((page: Page, key: number) => (
          <li className={styles.item} key={key}>
            <Link
              className={
                pathname == page.slug || pathname + "/" == page.slug
                  ? [styles.link, styles.link__active].join(" ")
                  : styles.link
              }
              href={page.slug}
            >
              {page.pagefield.map((field, fieldKey) => (
                <div key={fieldKey}>
                  <div className={styles.bubble}></div>
                  <span>{field.content}</span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For completion, I'll put here also my code that manage the API calls.

azureApi.ts:

```
import { getPagesEndpoint, getJobsEndpoint } from "./apiEndpoints";

export interface Page {
  idpage: number;
  imageurl: string;
  indexpage: number;
  pagefield: PageField[];
  slug: string;
}

export interface PageField {
  language: string;
  section: string;
  content: string;
}

export interface Job {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

class AzureApi {
  private readonly baseUrl: string;
  private readonly authToken: string;

  constructor() {
    this.baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL;
    this.authToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN;
  }

  async getPages(
    locale: string,
    params?: { [key: string]: any }
  ): Promise<Page[]> {
    return getPagesEndpoint(this.baseUrl, this.authToken, locale, params);
  }

  async getPosts(
    locale: string,
    params?: { [key: string]: any }
  ): Promise<Job[]> {
    return getJobsEndpoint(this.baseUrl, this.authToken, locale, params);
  }
}

export default AzureApi;
```

apiEndpoints.ts:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { setupCache } from "axios-cache-interceptor";
import { Page, Job } from "./azureApi";

const axios = setupCache(Axios);

interface ValidationError {
  message: string;
  errors: Record<string, string[]>;
}

export async function getPagesEndpoint(
  baseUrl: string,
  authToken: string,
  locale: string,
  params?: { [key: string]: any } // Define params as an object with string keys
): Promise<Page[]> {
  const endpoint = "/pages";
  return fetchData(endpoint, baseUrl, authToken, locale, params);
}

export async function getJobsEndpoint(
  baseUrl: string,
  authToken: string,
  locale: string,
  params?: { [key: string]: any }
): Promise<Job[]> {
  const endpoint = "/jobs";
  return fetchData(endpoint, baseUrl, authToken, locale, params);
}

// Reusable fetchData function
async function fetchData<T>(
  endpoint: string,
  baseUrl: string,
  authToken: string,
  locale: string,
  params?: { [key: string]: any }
): Promise<T> {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": authToken,
      },
      params: {
        language: locale,
        ...params,
      },
      cache: {
        ttl: 1000 * 60 * 3, // 3 minute.
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.get<T>(`${baseUrl}${endpoint}`, config);
    const data = response.data;

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (Axios.isAxiosError<ValidationError, Record<string, unknown>>(error)) {
      console.log(error.status);
      console.error(error.response);
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I just want to make it work as properly but still getting errors or undefined in my pages var.